# How to control Popup control display position when relative control position changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am using popup control to show validation error messages. I am setting popup control position based on parent control by using "PlacementTarget" property. Its working fine in most cases.(Screenshot-1[image]) But if I move Window to right side, then where there is not enough space to show popup control completely, it just moves to some random location. (Screenshot-2[image])

My question is, can I control position of popup control, when there is not much space (by getting an event or making it invisible) or somehow get notified that position is going to change.

XAML ->

```
<Popup x:Name="ErrorPopup "
   PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Part_TextBlock}"
   Placement="Right"
   HorizontalOffset="{TemplateBinding ErrorHorizontalOffset}"
   StaysOpen="True"
   VerticalOffset="{TemplateBinding ErrorVerticalOffset}">
```

Code Behind -

```
 void Owner_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 if (ErrorPopup == null)
      return;
            if (ErrorPopup.IsOpen)
            {
                var offset = ErrorPopup.HorizontalOffset;
                ErrorPopup.HorizontalOffset = offset + 1;
                ErrorPopup.HorizontalOffset = offset;
            }
        }
```